# Disable the dynamically created button that was pressed inside "aura:iteration" in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have multiple buttons being created against each file that needs to be uploaded, I want to disable the button that was clicked while other buttons should remain enabled

Here's my code

```
<aura:iteration aura:id="fid" items="{!v.files}" var="obj"  indexVar="index">
<tr>
    <td><div class="slds-truncate text-align: center" data-value="{!index}">
                   
                               <button type="button" onclick="{!c.doSave}" id="{!obj.Id}">Upload</button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </aura:iteration>
```

Here's the controller:

```
doSave: function(component, event, helper) {
        var allfiles= component.get("v.files");
        console.log('total number of files   ',allfiles.length);
        
        let fileIndex = event.target.closest("div").dataset.value;
           console.log('file index->   ',fileIndex);
             var f= component.get("v.files")[fileIndex];    
            console.log('### input file', f);
            var butn = event.target.id
            console.log("butn-> ",butn);
        
            helper.uploadHelper(component, event,f);
       
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to disable it directly:

```
event.target.disabled = true;
```